# Background color layer with pseudo css

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```css
 .product-item-info::after {
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            content:" ";
           height:300px;
            width:300px;
        }

.product-item-info {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item-info"></div>
```

Is it possible to create a color background layer as pseudo element, what I try now and is not working

```
.product-item-info:after {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    content:"";
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after) are `display: inline` by default. You'll want to set `display: block` for your `width` and `height` properties to be applied:

```css
.product-item-info::after {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    content:" ";
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block; /* this is what you need */
}

.product-item-info {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red; /* for demonstration purposes */
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item-info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do.

Also for pseudo elements you should use **"::"**

```css
.product-item-info {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.product-item-info::before {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  content: " ";
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.product-item-info::after {
  background-color: lightblue;
  content: " ";
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item-info"></div>
```

Comment: does not seems to produce anything I made a snippet and attached to post

Comment: bummer, missed @André Dion's answer by a minute :)